# Query rows (order items) that has combinations of specified values

Tags: mysql

I have order and order_items tables in MySQL. I want to fetch all orders having combination of provided skus as order items, but if any sku out side of filter is present dont return the order.

Filter : 1 , 2 ,3

```
order_items
100 | 1
101 | 2
102 | 3
103 | 1
103 | 2
103 | 3 
104 | 1
104 | 2
105 | 1
105 | 4
```

In example above  105 should not be shown in result since its not part of filter.

Show in result following orders if any of sku combination is present in items

```
1
2
3
1,2
1,3
2,3
1,2,3
```

I did try following but as can be seen in second query , I want to show result even if one of searched sku was present.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f12e0e4d401946b5617f74da8eb311a0

Comment: I still don't understand your criteria to filter 105.

Comment: `WHERE OrderNumber IN (1, 2, 3) AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM tablename WHERE OrderNumber NOT IN (1, 2, 3))`

Comment: I'm sure there are duplicates of this, but I don't have one in my saved list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following query with the sample dataset provided in your question to identify the orders then join on it as a subquery to pull your desired orders details.

The having clause is used to match your criteria with `count(CASE WHEN sku in (1,2,3) THEN sku END) > 0` identifying orders having your desired `skus` and `count(CASE WHEN sku not in (1,2,3) THEN sku END) = 0` ensuring that orders with other skus are filtered out.

```
select order_id, group_concat(sku) as skus
from order_items
group by order_id
having count(CASE WHEN sku in (1,2,3) THEN sku END) > 0 AND
       count(CASE WHEN sku not in (1,2,3) THEN sku END) = 0;
```

| order_id | skus |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 3 |
| 103 | 1,2,3 |
| 104 | 1,2 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3Q4cdhcwjjgki3H5aru7Nh/2)

[View working demo of shared dataset from your additional db fiddle using this approach](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f6429e434bb68520fa88793c9038f9d)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Perfect , thanks !